# Can we have some method to access NAF=true elements

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Can we have some method to access NAF=true elements. Currently my application has footer bar with NAF=true property. Element details is

NAF=true
Class = android.widget.RelativeLayout

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of screen? do you getting issue to find element from footer?

Comment: I am not able to add screenshot because it requires 10 reputation. I have only one reputation.

Comment: ok so you are not able to find element? what is actual issue?

Comment: Actually my applicaion has 3 tabs in footer as Location, rewards & news. Developers have used images for all three tabs which have same id, index, class & packages with NAF=true property. I want to tab on bottom tabs but not able to this. I tried to access these element through For Loop but it returns 1 although uiautomator is showing 3 child element.

Comment: ok do you getting those image index like 1,2,3?

Comment: If i am taking screenshot with "uiautomator dump" than it is showing 0 index for all three tabs but if i am taking screenshot with "uiautomator dump with compressed" than it is showing tabs like 1, 2 & 3. Can we access through it uiautomator compressed dump.

Comment: You can try this xpath //android.widget.GridView//android.widget.ImageView[1]

Comment: Thanks for your help...tap have performed through xpath.